# VideoCapture() camera index and QCameraInfo.availableCameras() index do not match

Tags: python, opencv, pyside2

I try to get a list of cameras to know which one I need to access given their names. However, the list I get with Qt's `QCameraInfo.availableCameras()` versus the index I supply to `cv2.VideoCapture()` seem to not always match, so if I have a camera named `"CAM1"` from `QCameraInfo.availableCameras()` at index `0`, and if I do `VideoCapture(0)`, I don't access `"CAM1"`.

Why and how to fix this?

```
import cv2
from PySide2.QtMultimedia import QCameraInfo

camera_list = []
index = 0

for cam in QCameraInfo.availableCameras():
    camera_list.append([index, cam.description()])
    index += 1

print(camera_list)

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is Windows has more than one backend for cameras and OpenCV uses the MSMF back-end while Qt uses the COM interface (named DirectShow) and the backends have different indexes. A solution is provided by use of `cv2.CAP_DSHOW`. You can do `cv2.VideoCapture(index + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` to fix the issue.